# Difficulties in saving a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, file, fs

I have a function which connects to api and extracts `particle`, `name` and `community_price` for many various items. It works well but now I want it to save the data in a json file. It should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "particle": "xxx",
        "name": "xxx",
        "community_price": "xxx"
    },
    {
        "particle": "xxx",
        "name": "xxx",
        "community_price": "xxx"
    },
    {
        "particle": "xxx",
        "name": "xxx",
        "community_price": "xxx"
    }
]
```

I spent plenty of time playing with `fs.writeFileSync` but unfortunately none of my attempts didn't work due to my poor knowledge of js. Any help is welcomed, the best answer will be selected. Thanks in advance!

Here's the function:

```
function get_community_price(){

  let url = 'https://example.com/api/IGetPrices/v4?key=' + backpackkey;
  var massive;
  let quality = '5';
  request({url:url, json:true},  function(err, res, body){
        if (err) console.log(err);

        massive = body.response.items;
        console.log('recieved comminty prices')
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1){

          let get_json = other.urltojson(data[i].ApiLink);
          let particle = get_json.particle
          let name = data[i].BuyLink;
              name = name.replace(/(\/Tradable).*/, '');
              name = name.replace(/.*(\/)/, '');
              name = name.replace(/\%20/g, ' ');
              name = name.replace(/\%27/g, '\'')

          let community_price = massive[name].prices[quality].Tradable.Craftable[particle].value;
          data[i].BuyPrice = community_price;

        }
         CreateOrders()    
      });
}
```

This is what I suppose it should be, but still doesn't work.

```
function get_community_price(){

  let url = 'https://example.com/api/IGetPrices/v4?key=' + backpackkey;
  var massive;
  let quality = '5';
  request({url:url, json:true},  function(err, res, body){
        if (err) console.log(err);

        massive = body.response.items;
        console.log('recieved comminty prices')
        for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1){

          let get_json = other.urltojson(data[i].ApiLink);
          let particle = get_json.particle
          let name = data[i].BuyLink;
              name = name.replace(/(\/Tradable).*/, '');
              name = name.replace(/.*(\/)/, '');
              name = name.replace(/\%20/g, ' ');
              name = name.replace(/\%27/g, '\'')

          let community_price = massive[name].prices[quality].Tradable.Craftable[particle].value;
          data[i].BuyPrice = community_price;

          var priceLog = [];

          priceLog.push({particle, name, community_price});
        }

  fs.writeFileSync('./app/comPrice.json', JSON.stringify(priceLog, null, 4));
  console.log('Fresh community price saved.');

  CreateOrders()    
  });
}
```

Comment: Please show your attempt at using `fs.writeFileSync` so we can explain what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I edited my question and added my attempt

Comment: Move `var priceLog = [];` outside of the for loop and you can set it to `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: @Gearge yeah, now it works well. Thanks for your help I really appreciate that a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the [official documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) tell that writeFileSync can be used as such:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const json = { /* Big object of whatever */ };
const path = "path/file.json";
fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(json));
```

I can't see any `fs.writeFileSync` in your code, but I guess this is what you want to do.

Comment: Yeah now I have realized that when posting here I need to show what I already tried. I edited my question, check it.

Comment: Well your code should work. Do you have an error or something ?

Comment: Before posting the question I had `priceLog.push({particle, name, community_price});`  written in 2 lanes and it throwed  `let community_price = massive[name].prices[quality].Tradable.Craftable[particle].value;
                                       ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'one of the names' of undefined`

Comment: Now It write it in 1 lane, it works but only saves 1 item instead of many

Comment: moving `var priceLog = [];` outside of the loop helped